# How do I link this switch statement to my program in c?:

Tags: c

HeaderFile.h

```
switch(hang) {
    case        0 :     printf("\t\t            \n\t\t \t    \n\t\t \t     \n\t\t \t    \n\t\t \t       \n\t\t \t    \n\t\t \t       \n\t\t                 \n\t\t \n\t     --------");
                        break;

    case        1 :     printf("\t\t            \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t     \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        2 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t     \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        3 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t     \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        4 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        5 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t   |   \n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        6 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / |   \n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        7 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / | \\\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        8 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / | \\\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t /     \n\t\t|      /         \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        9 : printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / | \\\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t /   \\\n\t\t|      /       \\\n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
}

/*
        ----------------
        |                   |
        |               (>///<)
        |                   |
        |                / | \
        |                   |
        |                /   \
        |               /     \
        |
    ----------
*/
```

---

Program.c

I want to display the pic here depending on the value of hang

I get the error:

```
HeaderFile.h:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'switch'
 switch(hang) {
 ^
```

Comment: Is this `switch()` statement the only source code in the file HeaderFile.h? What is in Program.c source code file? Why is there just a `switch()` in the HeaderFile.h without being part of a function? What is this for?

Comment: (1) `switch` statements must appear inside functions.  You could pretty easily wrap a function around yours, but then (2) function implementations do not belong in header files.  Your compiler will not enforce (2), however.  It's a convention -- a very strong one -- but not actually a requirement of the language itself.

Comment: I'm making a hangman game and I want to display the picture. Im also practicing headers, just tryna hide all the code away Should I just convert the switch to an if statement?

Comment: NO statement can appear outside a function.  Converting to `if` will not resolve your problem.  Additionally, "hid[ing] all the code away" is a terrible practice.  Splitting your program into separate functions is great, and spreading those functions among multiple `.c` files has its advantages, but for goodness' sake, do not try to *hide* your code.

Comment: The use of `if` has the same conditions as mentioned for `switch`.

Comment: Is there any more code somewhere? If so, we need to see it.

Comment: If the code is straight foward, first make a single C file with only library headers. When the code is working correctly, try moving a function to another .C file , with a .H header which declares what is in it, and link it into the project.

Comment: Putting code in a header is the opposite of "hiding" it.  If you distribute object code or a library, the header is the one part of the code the user will see and have access to.  Separate compilation and linking is the correct way to modularise your code and maximise cohesion and minimise coupling; this is an abuse of the pre-processor, and inclusion is _not_ linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (normally) don't put such code in a h-file. That code belongs in a c-file.

You could do something like:

hangman.h:

```
void printHangman(int hang);  // To tell other units that this function exists
```

hangman.c:

```
// The actual implementation
void printHangman(int hang)
{
    switch(hang) {

    case        0 :     printf("\t\t            \n\t\t \t    \n\t\t \t     \n\t\t \t    \n\t\t \t       \n\t\t \t    \n\t\t \t       \n\t\t                 \n\t\t \n\t     --------");
                        break;

    case        1 :     printf("\t\t            \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t     \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        2 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t     \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        3 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t     \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        4 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|\t    \n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        5 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t   |   \n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        6 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / |   \n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        7 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / | \\\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t       \n\t\t|                \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        8 :     printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / | \\\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t /     \n\t\t|      /         \n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    case        9 : printf("\t\t------------\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t  >/<\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t / | \\\n\t\t|\t   |\n\t\t|\t /   \\\n\t\t|      /       \\\n\t\t|\n\t     --------");
                        break;
    }

}
```

main.c:

```
#include "hangman.h"  // To know about the printHangman function

int main()    
{
    printHangman(3);  // To call the function
}
```

Comment: Strictly you can put anything you like in a header file, whether it makes syntactic or semantic sense depends on where it is `#include`'ed.  For example here if the  function`printHangman()` contained just the line `#include "HeaderFile.h"`, it would be valid and exactly as you have it here.  It would be unconventional perhaps, but not invalid.  Also the term "header file" would be misleading - it is an include file, but not a header in the usual sense.

Comment: @Clifford True, you can do that but that's pretty uncommon. I'll still say that the general rule is that you don't. BTW: I don't think I've used the term "header file" so I don't really understand that part of your comment.

Comment: My comment was intended as a clarification for the benefit of the reader,, not a criticism. The term "header" is used in the question.  You use the term h-file, and the "h" indicates "header".  It is a convention that makes sense only when the file is included at the _head_ of a source. The point is that _any_ file can be included anywhere; the pre-processor cares not, but if you expect the result to compile and link, the result must be valid in that context.